# How to execute profile last in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I have three different plugins. The execution of one of them is wrapped in a profile and disabled by default.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile-exec</id>
        <build>
        ...
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        ....
        </build>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false<activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        ...
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <id>test1</id>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        ...
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <id>test2</id>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run `mvn generate-sources -Pprofile-exec`, I see that the order of execution is the following:

```
test1
profile-exec
test2
```

what I am looking for is to obtain this order:

```
test1
test2
profile-exec
```

so that the profile is executed last. Is this possible? If so, how can it be achieved?

Comment: Are you trying to build the project for three different profiles at one command?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri No, I just want the three plugins to execute in the order I mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Plugins are invoked in the order they are defined. So:

1. Define all 3 of them in the right order inside `pluginManagement` section.
2. Turn on default plugins in `build/plugins` section.
3. Turn on the 3d plugin in the profile

If you had 3 *executions of the same plugin* and you wanted to set the order, you'd apply an additional trick:

1. Define all executions in the right order inside pluginManagement section.
2. For the one that's supposed to be turned off use `<phase>none</phase>` so that it's not actually run.
3. Then in profile declare the turned off execution **with the same id** and bind it to the appropriate phase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. *Plugins are invoked in the order they are defined.* That's what I thought, but why is the profile not executed first then? Is it necessary to use `pluginManagement`? From the docs, I see *it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one*. But I don't really need any project to inherit from this one

Comment: @Paolo, _why is the profile not executed first then_ because there's no single list of plugins where you define order. You declared couple of plugins here and another one there. _it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one_ - maybe the doc is a bit misleading, but that's not the sole purpose of `pluginManagement`. It's more about having a common place to _describe_ (but not add) plugins, and then decide where in the project you really want them to be invoked.

Comment: Could you share an example for both scenarios? Thanks